# Jekyll: Change compiled directory for only sass file in _config.yml

Tags: css, sass, jekyll

I am working with Jekyll and Github Pages, and I would like to change the directory for where my Sass files are compiled from `_site/css` to another folder of my choosing.  Please keep in mind that I only want to change the directory for where the Sass file compiles to, not any other file.

Do I need to specify this in the `_config.yml` file, and if so, what is the syntax for that?

The reason I am asking is because my `.gitignore` file ignores the `_site` folder, therefore when I push to my Github Pages my site does not render any css changes because the entire `_site` folder is ignored, thus ignoring the css file contained within.

Comment: Not sure where your problem comes from (sass/scss nor processed, wrong css path). Did you have a githut repository url ?

Comment: Okay, so being a n00b to Jekyll & Github Pages, here is my issue...  Github Pages ignores the '_site' folder in Jekyll.  The '_site/css' folder is where the scss files compile.  Because Github Pages ignores the '_site' folder, any subfolders within are also ignored, meaning my '_site/css' folder, containing the css files is ignored.  Therefore, my Github Pages site built in Jekyll will not render the css.

Comment: gh-pages doesn't care about your `_site` folder. The problem is elsewhere. That's why I ask you for a github repository url. I need to see you code, not to copy or blame, but to spot your problem.

Comment: Here's the link to the repo, David.  (https://github.com/david-brener/test)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `_layouts/default.html`, change :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/app.css">
```

for :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ site.baseurl }}/css/app.css">
```

Comment: That did the trick!  Thanks so much for your help, David!  I realize that the link was incorrect but what I didn't know, or didn't realize, was the adding of `{{site.baseurl}}` to the beginning of the href.  Once I did that, and corrected the path, the css now works wonderfully!  I spent a whole day yesterday trying to get this working!

Comment: And maybe you can approve my answer.